# Create array by comparing JSON data to an array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, nsdictionary

I'm getting access to 'hotel' from json file:

```
NSArray *hotel = [jsonObject valueForKeyPath:@"location.hotel"];
```

With print out like (UPDATED):

```
<__NSCFArray 0x7b254d70>(
{
    test = A;
    hotel =     (
                {
            luxuryHotels = hotel1;

        },
                {
            luxuryHotels = hotel2;

        },
```

I want to check if the array 'hotel' contains objects from another array 'myHotels' and if it does, create an array with only those objects.

```
NSArray *myHotels = [NSArray arrayWithArray:hotel.luxuryHotels];
NSMutableArray *hotel2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSArray *object in hotel) {
    NSMutableSet *set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: object];
    NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray: myHotels];
    [set1 intersectSet: set2];
    NSArray *resultArray = [set1 allObjects];
    NSLog(@"resultArray is %@",resultArray);
    [hotel2 addObject:resultArray];
}
```

The print for 'hotel2' is something like: (
),( hyatt
),(
)

Is there a way to get a string of only hyatt? Or a way to combine the dictionaries of the array so it show as on list if there are more than one hotel listed?

Comment: The structure of what [jsonObject valueForKeyPath:@"location.hotel"] returns is not clear. Please post the actual output of a log of hotel.

Comment: see update, let me know what else i can provide.

Comment: I don't think you have a grasp on the data structure, and we certainly don't.  Add NSLog statements to dump your arrays at each step.  And what this means I don't know, if `hotel` is supposedly an array: `hotel.luxuryHotels`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still not 100% clear what the data structure looks like but you could try something like this

Collapse your initial data structure (array of arrays) into just an array, then convert this into a mutable set

```
NSArray *flattenedHotels = [jsonObject valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfArrays.location.hotel"];

NSMutableSet *hotels = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:flattenedHotels];
```

Next you just perform an intersection with `myHotels`

```
[hotels intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:myHotels]];

NSArray *result = hotels.allObjects;
```